# proper way of handling drop events in jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery UI `droppable` and `draggable`. Based on what element was dropped on some canvas different functions are invoked. So right now it's something like this:

```
$('#myCanvas').droppable({
    drop: function (e, ui) {
        if (draggableId === "idA") {
            functionA();
        } else if (draggableId === "idB") {
            functionB();
        } else if (draggableId === "idC") {
            functionC();
        }
    }
});
```

I wanna get rid of that ugly complexions. It looks like a polymorphism problem, but I don't really know how to handle this in such a case. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var fns = {
    idA: functionA,
    idB: functionB,
    idC: functionC
}
$('#myCanvas').droppable({
    drop: function (e, ui) {
        var fn = fns[draggableId];
        if($.isFunction(fn)){
            fn();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: That's elegant solution. Thank You!